# false expression must have a constant value in visual studio 2022 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022

hello there i was writing a code in a compiler but my compiler had this error :"false expression must have a constant value" in one of the program lines
i used other compilers but they didn't say this and i could write my program , but in visual studio 2022 it gives me the error
the sample of the program is  :

```
 stack<char> stack;
 queue<char> queue;
string str;
cin >> str;
char ch[str.length()];
```

the error is in the

```
char ch[str.length()];
```

i dont know how to fix this
i would be glad if you guys help me in this

Comment: Some compilers have enabled-by-default extensions to allow this, but C++ does not provide this feature.

Comment: What's actually unclear about the error message? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable-length arrays is not C++ standard, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Because `str.length()` is known at runtime, but the size of the array has to be known at compile-time, this will cause an error.

You should use `std::vector` instead:

Replace:

```
char ch[str.length()];
```

With:

```
std::vector<char> ch(str.length());
```